# SharePoint 2013 Variations Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, variations

I am using powershell to manage the creation of some site variations following this tutorial:

http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2013/7/23/automate-variations-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell-c

[image]

It is working but now I need to enable Human Translation and Machine Translation. How can I do that using powershell?? Currently I am using the below code. In Allow human translation it shows that No column found. Same for Allow machine translation. It shows me no column found. Please help.

```
$item = $list.Items.Add();
$item["Title"] = $label_DE_Title;
$item["Description"] = $label_DE_Description;
$item["Allow human translation"]=$true;
$item["Language"] = $label_DE_Language;
$item["Locale"] = $label_DE_Locale;
$item["Hierarchy Creation Mode"] = $label_DE_HierarchyCreationMode;
$item["Is Source"] = $label_DE_IsSource;
$item["Hierarchy Is Created"] = $false;
```

Comment: Try to get the fieldname with $list.Fields | fl

Answer (score 5):

You need to set correct properties while creating Variation Labels, see example for Swedish label (c#) when both Machine and Human Translations are enabled using `MachineTranslationEnabled` and `HumanTranslationEnabled`

```
                    Title = "sv-SE",
                    FlagControlDisplayName = "Svenska",
                    Language = "sv-SE",
                    Locale = 1053,
                    HierarchyCreationMode = CreationMode.PublishingSitesAndAllPages,
                    IsSource = false,
                    MachineTranslationEnabled = true,
                    HumanTranslationEnabled = true,
                    HumanTranslationLanguage = 1053
```

Could you use `IsMachineTranslationEnabledField` and `IsHumanTranslationEnabled` with PowerShell to see if you're referring to correct columns? Sorry, I can't test it myself at the moment

Comment: Hi,That is what i would like to know is what is column name for Human and Machine Translation. I have try Allow human translation,Human Translation, HumanTranslationEnabled ..but nothing is working and it shows me column not found. Can you please tell me from where can i check column name

Answer (score 0):

The column name is  "Is Machine Translation Enabled".

This worked for me

```
$item["Is Machine Translation Enabled"] = $true;
```